# Would you help me with use and employ?

Tags: vocabulary

> Our embassy in Paris *employs/uses* around twenty full-time staff.

Would anybody tell me which one and *why*?

Answer (score 2):

They are synonyms. Either one could be used in this context; however, you have misspelled *employs*.

It's hard to choose one over the other, because you have not told us what you are trying to communicate.

If you the speaker is trying to emphasize how many people are on the embassy payroll, then *employs* would probably be the better word. On the other hand, if the speaker is trying to emphasize how many people are required to perform embassy functions on a day-to-day basis, then *uses* might be a better word.

Answer (score 1):

It should almost certainly be "employs".

When referring to a person, "to employ" always denotes hiring someone to do (paid) work. It seems probable that this is what your sentence is trying to say—"We have around twenty people working in our embassy full-time."

"To use", on the other hand, is a very general term that can denote getting any kind of practical benefit out of the object. Used of people, it often has negative connotations—if you "use" someone, you have treated them impersonally, or even exploitatively, as a means to an end.

I'm sure there *could* be context that mitigates this negative sense, but in all likelihood, you want "employs".